# Get $_POST from multiple checkboxes with same value in different row

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

How can i put my form like this in database 
this is the database photo

[image: database]

and this is my form photo

[image: form]

i need to manipulate the database through this form please help

this is the code of the form how can i make a submit file for this:

```
</style>

<form action="submitRegister.php" method="post">
<div class = "register">
<div class="container">
</script>
<h2><b><font color="black">User Group Maintenace</font></b></h2>
<img src="icon/logss.png" width="972" height="54" alt=""/>
<th> <label for="ACode"><b><font color="black">Access Code</font></b></label>
       <input type="text" id="ACode" name="ACode" required /></th>
      <label for="Desc"><b><font color="black">Description</font></b></label>
       <input type="text" id="Desc" name="Desc" required /></th>
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="tabs">
            <li class="active">Transaction</li>
            <li>Files</li>
             <li>View</li>
            <li>Print</li>
            <li>Maintenance</li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>
            <ul id="tab">
            <li class="active">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="DateEntry" value="DataEntry" checked="checked">Data Entry<br></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="Verify" value="Verify">Verify Voucher<br></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="signiture" value="signiture">Affix Signiture<br></th>
    </tr>
    <TR>
      <th></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="UnVerify" value="UnVerify">UnVerify Voucher<br></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="assigncheck" value="assigncheck">Assign Check/Finalize Entries<br></th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="voucherfile" value="voucherfile" checked="checked">Voucher File<br></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="approvevoucher" value="approvevoucher">Approve Voucher<br></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="unassigncheck" value="unassigncheck" checked="checked">Unassign Check<br></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="disapprovevoucher" value="disapprovevoucher">Disapprove Voucher<br></th
    </tr>
    </table>
            </li>
        </form>
            <li>
                    <table>
        <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="approveuser" value="approveuser">Approve User<br></th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="payees" value="payees" checked="checked">Payees<br></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="chartsofaccount" value="chartsofaccount" checked="checked">Charts Of Account<br></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="signatories" value="signatories" checked="checked">Signatories<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="company" value="company">Company Profile<br></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="users" value="users">Users<br></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="department" value="department" checked="checked">Department<br></th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="Useraccess" value="Useraccess">User Group<br></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
            </li>
                  <li>
                  <table>
        <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="AccountBalance" value="AccountBalance">Account Balance<br></th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="CheckInventory" value="CheckInventory" checked="checked">Check Inventory<br></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="Checkseries" value="Checkseries" checked="checked">Check Series<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="viewvoucher" value="viewvoucher">View Voucher<br></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
            </li>
                       <li>
                  <table>
        <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="checks">Checks<br></th>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="reprintchecks" value="reprintchecks" checked="checked">Reprint Checks<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="reports" value="reports">Reports<br></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="list" value="list">List<br></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
            </li>
                       <li>
                  <table>
        <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="backup" value="backup">Backup<br></th>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="restore" value="restore" checked="checked">Restore<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="transferdata" value="transferdata">Transfer Data<br></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="markchecks" value="markchecks">Mark Checks<br></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: why exactly are you trying to achieve and what is the problem you are facing?? Its unclear.

Comment: i need to create a submit to insert data like the photo on the database using that form

Comment: then create fields in/& table, receive data in the `submitRegister.php` and save it to db, whats the issue?

Comment: how can i put the data with same value in different row?

Comment: So for each checkbox, you want to insert a new row, with it marked as either checked (yes) or unchecked (no)?

Comment: yes like if i like click data entry it will be inserted in db like in the photo above

Comment: One way to do this is to create a php array with all the checkboxes, ie. `$checkboxes = array("DataEntry", "Verify",...);`. Then loop over that array, checking if those are checked or not, and inserting them accordingly, ie. `foreach($checkboxes as $value){ $YesNo = isset($_POST[$value]) ? 'yes' : 'no'; // INSERT INTO yourTable (rr_modulecode, rr_create) VALUES ('$value', '$YesNo');`